# DemoSalesPerson2.java:15: error: constructor SalesPerson in class SalesPerson cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Whenever I compile my code, I receive the following errors:

> constructor SalesPerson in class SalesPerson cannot be applied to
>   given types; error: constructor Player in class Player cannot be
>   applied to given types;

But it doesn't list any types. The code in question is

Modify the DemoSalesperson application so each Salesperson has a successive ID number from 111 through 120 and a sales value that ranges from $25,000 to $70,000, increasing by $5,000 for each successive Salesperson. Save the file as DemoSalesperson2.java.*/

SalesPerson class:

```
public class SalesPerson {

        // Data fields for Salesperson include an integer ID number and a double annual sales amount
    private int idNumber;

    private double salesAmount;

    //Methods include a constructor that requires values for both data fields, as well as get and set methods for each of the data fields.
    public SalesPerson(int idNum, double salesAmt) {

        idNumber = idNum;
        salesAmount = salesAmt;

    }

    public int getIdNumber() {

        return idNumber;
    }

    public void setIdNumber(int idNum) {

        idNumber = idNum;
    }

    public double getSalesAmount() {
        return salesAmount;
    }

    public void setSalesAmount(double salesAmt) {
        salesAmount = salesAmt;

    }
}
```

Driver:

```
public class DemoSalesPerson2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SalesPerson s1 = new SalesPerson(111, 0);

        final int NUM_PERSON = 10;
        SalesPerson[] num = new SalesPerson[NUM_PERSON];
        for (int x = 1; x < num.length; x++) {
              // NUM_PERSON

            num[x] = new SalesPerson((111 + x + "|" + 25000 + 5000 * (x)));
            System.out.println(x + "    " + s1.getIdNumber() + " " + s1.getSalesAmount());

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: How I Modify the DemoSalesperson2 application so each Salesperson has a successive ID number from 111 through 120 and a sales value that ranges from $25,000 to $70,000, increasing by $5,000 for each successive Salesperson.

Comment: And what are your efforts so far to achieve this?

Comment: 1    9999 0.0
2    9999 0.0
3    9999 0.0
4    9999 0.0
5    9999 0.0
6    9999 0.0
7    9999 0.0
8    9999 0.0
9    9999 0.0                        I've achieved this but unable to modify this

Comment: Your `SalesPerson` is expecting two paramaters, one `int` and one `double`, but you are only passing a single `String`

Answer (score 0):

Change this: `num[x] = new SalesPerson((111 + x + "|" + 25000 + 5000 * (x)));`
to this: `num[x] = new SalesPerson((111 + x), (25000 + 5000 * (x)));`

You had it right here `SalesPerson s1 = new SalesPerson(111, 0);`.

Notice the difference between the two constructor calls.

As Sssss pointed out, you're handing in a String as the constructor param when your method requires two ints.

Code jotted down here, haven't tested it. Should get you pointed in the right direction however.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DemoSalesPerson2
{

   public static void main(String[] args)

   {

   SalesPerson[] num = new SalesPerson[10];

   final int START_NUM =111;
   final double START_SALARY=25_000;
   for (int x =0; x<num.length; x++) {

   num[x] =new SalesPerson(START_NUM+x,START_SALARY+5000*(x));
  System.out.println(num[x].getIdNumber()+"   "+num[x].getSalesAmount() );
  }



}}
```

try this!!